# How to tell VoiceOver that a control has animated away?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

User taps control and a different view comes up, animated. VoiceOver still highlights the removed control and it is stuck. User can't interact with the view.

This is not in a UIViewController but a custom UIView subclass.

How to tell VoiceOver to update its presentation or state when something appeared or disappeared with animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post an accessibility notification to indicate that the layout or the full screen of content has changed and select a new element.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification
                                elementToSelect);
```